# Floating the previous value with present value to right in jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have quick question about jQuery, I am stuck at small issue. I created the form what it does basically is when you press the submit it will show the value downside. What I am trying to achieve is to make the block with previous value and the present value and whenever more value will be enter it will move to right. I do not want to use any plug in

so instead user enter value

```js
//to display the name below
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#print').html($('#fname').val())
  $('#lname1').html($('#lname').val())
  $('#phone1').html($('#phone').val())
  $('#email1').html($('#email').val())
    // to print the value
  $('#lname').val("")
  $('#fname').val("")
  $('#phone').val("")
  $('#email').val("")
})

//validation check 
function checkforblank() {
    //  if(document.getElementById('fname').value ())
    if ($('#fname').val() == '') {
      // alert("please enter your first name");
      //document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor= "red";

    }
    /* if ($('#lname').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter your last name");
          // breaking the action 
      }
          
           if ($('#phone').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter your Phone Number");
          // breaking the action 
      }
           if ($('#email').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter Email");
          // breaking the action 
     }*/
  } //closing function brackets
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Validation Form</h1>

<label>First Name:
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</label>
<br>

<label>Last Name:
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</label>
<br>

<label>Phone:
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
</label>
<br>

<label>Email:
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
</label>
<br>

<!-- dont forget to give the form id to connect-->
<button onClick="checkforblank()" id="btn">submit</button>

<div id="print"></div>
<div id="lname1"></div>
<div id="phone1"></div>
<div id="email1"></div>
```

For instance previous value is  and so on. My question is can you use the push in jquery to achieve this ?

```
New Value : xyz             Previous value : danny
ax                                           texas
23                                           asdf
kj@gmail.com                                 asdf@gmail.com
```

I have tried several function like appendTo , prepend, clone but I do not what property will help me to achieve the result.

Thank you

Comment: Are you only concerned with the immediately previous form input or do you want to show _all_ previous inputs.

Comment: I am trying to show last 5 previous input

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a basic template of the result ,by default it would be hidden

as soon as you enter the values ,it would clone the template and current values would be appended to the result,it will have **current** class

and for all other past values,i have removed current and added a past class to it.

for the styling purpose, i have used flex. div.Results which would have the current and past div ,it would be flex-direction:row and current/past divs would have column direction and i have used order to make sure that by default currentResults would be displayed first and all other past results would follow the current results(check the changeOrder) functionality in the code

check this snippet

```js
//to display the name below
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var Results = $(".Results");
  var ResultDiv = Results.find('div.colFlex');
  var currTemplate = $(" .current");
  var pastTemplate;
  var order = 1;
  if (ResultDiv.length > 0) {


    order = order + 1;

    pastTemplate = currTemplate.clone();
    pastTemplate
    pastTemplate.find('.headerStatus').html("Past Values:");
    pastTemplate.find('.headerStatus').show();
    pastTemplate.removeClass('current');
    pastTemplate.addClass("past");
    pastTemplate.addClass('colFlex')
    pastTemplate.appendTo(Results);
  }


  Results.addClass('flexclass');


  currTemplate.find('#print').html($('#fname').val());
  currTemplate.find('#lname1').html($('#lname').val());
  currTemplate.find('#phone1').html($('#phone').val());
  currTemplate.find('#email1').html($('#email').val());
  currTemplate.addClass('colFlex');
  currTemplate.appendTo(Results);
  currTemplate.find('.headerStatus').show();
  // to print the value
  $('#lname').val("")
  $('#fname').val("")
  $('#phone').val("")
  $('#email').val("");
  changeOrders();
});

function changeOrders() {
    var Results = $(".Results");
    var colFlexDiv = Results.find('div.past');
    var length = colFlexDiv.length;

    $('.Results .current').addClass('order');
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      $(colFlexDiv[i]).css({
        'order': i
      });
    }
  }
  //validation check 

function checkforblank() {
    //  if(document.getElementById('fname').value ())
    if ($('#fname').val() == '') {
      // alert("please enter your first name");
      //document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor= "red";

    }
    /* if ($('#lname').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter your last name");
          // breaking the action 
      }
          
           if ($('#phone').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter your Phone Number");
          // breaking the action 
      }
           if ($('#email').val() == ''){
          alert("please enter Email");
          // breaking the action 
     }*/
  } //closing function brackets
```

```css
.Results {
  display: none;
}
.flexclass {
  display: flex;
}
.colFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.order {
  order: -1;
}
.headerStatus {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
}
.Results div.colFlex {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Validation Form</h1>

<label>First Name:
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</label>
<br>

<label>Last Name:
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</label>
<br>

<label>Phone:
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
</label>
<br>

<label>Email:
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
</label>
<br>
<!-- dont forget to give the form id to connect-->
<button onClick="checkforblank()" id="btn">submit</button>
<div class="current">
  <label class="headerStatus">current values:</label>
  <div id="print"></div>
  <div id="lname1"></div>
  <div id="phone1"></div>
  <div id="email1"></div>
</div>
<div class="Results">

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what I needed but I couldn't understand what you did. can you explain little bit your  code. It did gave me the solution but I was looking for beginner solution. thank you for your help

Comment: I have edited my explanation in the answer ..please let me know if you need anything more

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution you can use `prepend` here instead of `replace`. [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

html : create a `div`  tag to which these details go to

```
<div id ="foo"></div>
```

---

script:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $("#foo").prepend($('#fname').val())
    $("#foo").prepend($('#lname').val())
    $("#foo").prepend($('#phone').val())
    $("#foo").prepend($('#email').val())
        //rest of your code..
})
```

Comment: my first option was using prepend but it all I am getting is the input field below not the value store inside the input field